# BoilerPlate Configure Options for LoginPath and AccessDeniedPath

Tags: asp.net-identity, aspnetboilerplate

I've been using ASP.NET Boilerplate as a template for my application as a starting point. I have chosen the Multipage web application option with the included login, register, user, role and tenant management pages configured.

While trying to implement my permission using the documentation for using `IPermissionChecker`, I ran into an infinite loop per-say.

If I try to access a controller, or controller action that is using `AbpMvcAuthorize` or `AbpAuthorize` I get redirected to the login page.

On the surface that seems reasonable, however, the returnUrl is set to the Url that I was just trying to access.  So upon attempting to login again I am ultimately redirected to the login page since the return url is denying access to the user.

Since .NET Core is built on Identity I was looking where I could configure some of the options that pertain to the Login Path, the Access Denied Path and possibly the Cookie Name that is being used.

Something like this :

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => 
        {
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
        });
```

However, simply adding this sort of Code in the `startup.cs`or event in the `AuthConfigurer.cs Configure()` method does not seem to change this behavior.

If anyone can provide some guidance on this matter I would appreciate it.  I thought of adding a new Filter and override the  `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method, but simply being able to set these properties somewhere seems like it would be simpler less complicated way of doing things.

**UPDATE**

To give some clarification, here is how we have implemented `IPermissionChecker` its fairly simple, this application does not require a extremely granular set of permissions with childPermissions. It is very basic and stems from what the default Permissions was when we started with the template.

```
public override void SetPermissions(IPermissionDefinitionContext context)
{
    context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Users, L("Users"));
    context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Roles, L("Roles"));
    context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_About, L("About"));
    context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Builders, L("Builders"));
    context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Association, L("Association"));
    context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_DraftType, L("DraftType"));        
}
```

Then we have a set of Constants in the `PermissionNames.cs`

```
public static class PermissionNames
{
    public const string Pages_Users = "Pages.Users";

    public const string Pages_Roles = "Pages.Roles";

    public const string Pages_About = "Pages.About";

    public const string Pages_Builders = "Pages.Builders";

    public const string Pages_Association = "Pages.Associations";

    public const string Pages_DraftType = "Pages.DraftType";

}
```

When attempting to enforce those permissions we use it with attribute annotations

```
[HttpGet]
[AbpMvcAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_DraftType)]
    public IActionResult Index()
```

As Stated above, this all appears to work correctly. Its just that if I do not have permissions to access `~/DraftType` then I am redirected to the `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FDraftType`.

Re-entering my credentials attempts to take me back to '/DraftType' but since I have no permissions to access that page I'm again taken to the login url as seen above.

Unless we manually remove the returnUrl parameter from the address bar in the browser the user can not get back into the application.  Which is why I'd like to be able to make the distinction between `LoginPath` and `AccessDeniedPath` so that, when access is denied the user is directed to a `Forbidden Access` error page.

If the user's session has expired but do have permission but need to re-authenticate I need the behavior to remain the same. They are redirected to the Login url with a ReturnURL that will allow them to get directly where they attempted to go.

Comment: can you share your code / implementation of `IPermissionChecker` please?

Comment: Updated my question with some additional information as requested

Comment: i see.  in my use of this framework i have not `tested` this scenario to be honest.  and it doesn't sound like you're doing anything out of the ordinary.  i wonder if it's worthwhile submitting an issue on the github repo?